# Integration/metadatalayeron top of two databases - Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, metadata

I am supposed to  create  metadata layer on top of  two inventory databases, local DB1 and local DB2.
For each object (table name, column name, etc.) that is present in each local db, there should be three representations (in the same row in the metadata table):

1. a canonical representation(global level) for the object. This is a representation that identifies the object globally (see first column in the example table below).
2. a local representation for local DB1:it refers to the name of the column in local DB1 that represents that same object. Also we create another column in the metadata table to store the data type of that column in local DB1 (see columns 2 and 3 in example table below)
3. a local representation for local DB2:  it refers to the name of the column in local DB2 that represents that same object. In addition, we need to store its data type in local DB2 (see columns 4 and 5 in example table below)
   [image: Example Implementation of Meta data table]

The metadata table contains the following columns:

1. Column 1: Contains the name of a field(canonical representation).
2. Column 2: Contains the corresponding name of the same field in DB1(local DB1 name)
3. Column 3: Contains the name of the data type of that field in DB1
4. Column 4: Contains a function stored as a string, that maps the canonical name to the DB1 name (if applicable)
5. Column 5: Contains the corresponding name (local DB2 name) of the same field in DB2
6. Column 6: Contains the data type of that field in DB2
7. column 7: Contains a function to map the canonical name to the DB2 name (if applicable)

[image: select * from v$version]

How to use select query to display data of these local databases using this  meta_data table.

Comment: This is an implementation of a data catalog. Depending on your requirements you may wish to simply implement an external product for this. What happens when DB3 comes into the picture? What happens when "Ticket_ID is represented by two different columns? How to start? Open SQL Developer and create the table!

Comment: Okay. So for this I just need to create a new table using local db1 and db2. Right?

Comment: This is Oracle right? In Oracle, I suggest you create a new _schema_, give it a name like `datacatalog`, and create all of your data catalog objects in there. Don't create this application in db1 or db2

Comment: Is there any way to create 1 table as shown in the Figure.  If I created the columns of the table as shown in figure. How am I supposed to enter values like "data type" etc and how the data can be accessed from the db1 and db2 tables.

Comment: Yes you can create a table as described in the figure. What specific problem are you having? Why does Db2 need to access this table? A “human” needs to decide what field maps to what. If you are using Oracle and you want a user interface you would often use “Oracle Forms”

Comment: Can you confirm you are using Oracle? Can you run select * from v$version and edit your question and paste the result.

Comment: Right now you need to create a new database and create your table in there.

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer. The assignment wants me to integrate the two databases in one table such that I can view the data by running queries on Metadata Table. Thank you for suggesting the Idea of Oracle forms, I understood that. But for demonstration purpose how can I populate this table so that I can view and query the data available on local databases. I created new database and new table as you suggested.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is not a database, it's a client tool. Anyway.... knowing that is an assignment makes a difference because now we know we aren't solving a real world problem, and I know not to suggest things like third party data catalog or Oracle forms. To populate the table you run insert statements inside Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Yes, that's where I am facing problem in insertion. I can use insert statements to enter field names and data type names but what about mapping functions.
For example:
Column 4: Contains a function stored as a string, that maps the canonical name to the DB1 name

Comment: And If I ran query on this Table it would simply return me field names and data type names. Is it possible to access the data values for these field names using this meta_data table or not?
I apologize if my questions are causing any confusion.

Comment: _Contains a function stored as a string, that maps the canonical name to the DB1 name (if applicable)_ I don't understand this - you have already mapped it by populating column1,2,3 so there is no need for a function.

Comment: Okay, understood. Thanks.

Comment: What about using this meta_data table to query data of these local tables. Is that even possible? or it can just return the field names and data type names?

Comment: Yes it's possible to access the actual data using dynamic SQL, but dynamic SQL has it's own issues. Will you only ever have two databases? If that's the case you would be much better off simply building views that stitch the data together. It's quite a technically demanding exercise to build a metadata based integration layer. Anyway what you need to do is use your metadata table to build a SQL statement into a string, then you can run that string using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

Comment: Yes. My first instinct was to use views only but then the assignment had following instruction.
Do not create views on top of the existing tables of local DB1 and local DB2. You need to create an actual table with metadata about DB1 tables and fields, and DB2 tables and fields, similar to the example.

Comment: I don't know if this is a college / university assignment or a work assignment but frankly, it's wrong and overcomplicated (or badly explained). Anyway.... I think you need to edit your question and add the result of this: `select * from v$version`, then you need to provide an example of what SQL statement you expect to be generated out of this table - a `union all` I guess? Then you need to explain how you want that to be  triggered / generated. This is why I suggest views - it solves all of these problems